# When importing into Google Collab: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

using pandas in google colaboratory, I am attempting to import a .csv file named 'gifted.csv'. Using the following code:

`df=pd.read_csv('/content/gifted.csv')`

I have ran the pandas library as pd, but whenever I run the code, it does not function and the following error appears.
`enter code hereTypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

i dont know where the csv is located but try

```
df=pd.read_csv('content/gifted.csv')
```

without the '/' before the content

the error does not imply for it but try it.

more check about the import did the package installed well.